# My Adobe XD plugin isn't showing up in the Plugin menu

Tags: plugins, adobe-xd

I've started building a new plugin for Adobe XD, but for some reason, I can't see it in the plugin menu, even after several reloads.

I'm pretty sure I structured the folder correctly and I'm building in the correct `develop` folder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Plugin location

Make sure your plugin is in XD's `develop` folder. You can find that folder here:

- macOS:

  - `~/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe/Adobe\ XD\ CC/`
- Windows:

  - `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\Adobe.CC.XD_adky2gkssdxte\LocalState\`

The [XD plugin API docs](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/structure/location.html) have more information on plugin location.

## Manifest errors

Errors in the [plugin manifest](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/structure/manifest.html) are the most likely culprit.

Here's an example of a `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "id": "YOUR_ID_HERE",
    "name": "Name of Your Plugin",
    "version": "0.0.1",

    "description": "Description of your plugin.",
    "icons": [
        { "width": 96, "height": 96, "path": "images/icon@2x.png" }
    ],

    "host": {
        "app": "XD",
        "minVersion": "13.0.0"
    },

    "uiEntryPoints": [
        {
            "type": "menu",
            "label": "Hello World",
            "commandId": "helloCommand",
            "shortcut": { "mac": "Cmd+Shift+P", "win": "Ctrl+Shift+P" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the `icons` and `uiEntryPoints` values are *arrays of objects*, not an objects.